# ModalViewController is hidden under a view

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, uiwindow

I am working on a photo previewing component. Now I met a problem for showing a modalViewController: When I want to display a preview view, what I am doing is like this:

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
EKImageViewer *viewer = [[EKImageViewer alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[window addSubview:viewer];
[window addSubview:viewer.preview];
[window addSubview:viewer.shareBtn];//A UIButton control
```

When closing the preview view, What I am doing is like this:

```
[viewer.shareBtn removeFromSuperview];
[viewer.preview removeFromSuperview];
[viewer removeFromSuperview];
```

When Tapping the shareBtn(UIButton) in preview component, I want to display a modal view(MFMailComposeViewController):

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

There something weird happen: the modalViewController is shown under the preview component. Only when I close the preview component, could I see the the modalViewController. Is There anything I was wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont add `viewer` on top of `window`. Instead add on your `rootViewController.view.` That should resolve this. If possible try not to add anything apart from `rootViewController` on `window`. Whatever you want to add after that can be added on `rootViewController`.